# Help with an alpha brush - camera setup

Tags: materials

So I was trying to make my own alpha brushes.
but I have a problem with the opacity at the edges of the brush...
Not being so familiar with blender nodes i'm really not sure how to adjust the settings to achieve a smooth transition outwards.

I think likely its either my camera settings or the adjustments to the image...
I'm still trying to adjust the settings and keep tweaking it... but hopefully someone has some ideas what might be causing the problem.

rendered image also has a slight gradient visible below ... ill try playing with the distance... maybe that will help.?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[you tube vid of problem](https://youtu.be/5kUP6H5msKs)

Answer (score 1):

your sample bias setting is screwing you over here. I tried your first file, and just loading as a texture, and using it without any editing, on Area plane, anchored mode, and custom falloff set to all max, it worked fine. I would however suggest you didn't use the fade on the edges, seeing how this alpha is a full object with hard edges, and not truly just a texture, but a belt buckle...?

in any case, blender accepts black-backed alphas by default, because they're easier to produce and provide much more detail in the most often used direction. Generally, grey-backed alphas (the background grey at 50% brightness) is used in alphas with both positive and negative deformation.

Comment: Thanks so much!, yes I will keep practicing to make better renders for my brushes, but that helps a ton :)

I marked it as the answer, but if you do have a little extra time may ask...what would you recommend as sample bias and how does that work?

Comment: Actually I found it sorry I was confused initially if sample bias was in the camera - but then I found it on the brush - so no explanation needed ;P Thanks a million now it all works and I know why and how to adjust what I need!  win win

Comment: at 0, black=flat -use for ridges, bumps, and surface objects, like lug nuts, scales, and ribbing-----
at -.5, 50%grey=flat -use for surface details, like bolts, scars, terrain and warped plating---------
at -1, white=flat -use for indents- gashes, gaps, handholds and bullet holes